# Concurrency: synchronized versus lock

Tags: java, concurrency

What is the difference between synchronized and lock in Java?

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "lock".

Comment: Yep,tag your question with 'homework' if it is, please.

Comment: He probably means the difference between "synchronized" and the Lock implementations http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Answer (score 2):

`synchronized` is a language keyword; Locks are objects.

When a method or block of code is marked synchronized, you are saying that some lock object (which could be specified in the syntax of synchronized) must be obtained by the method or block before it can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Both `synchronized` keyword and `Lock` objects are used to achieve synchronization in Java. `Synchronized` operates on monitor mechanisms that each `Object` in Java possess while lock is a simpler object which is a building block of the monitor. i believe basically the question is about the difference between a monitor and a lock.

A lock such as a `semaphore`, is a simple mechanism that can achieve synchronization by mutual exclusion only. If one thread acquired (`lock.acquire()`) a particular lock no other thread can acquire the same lock until the first thread releases it (`lock.release()`). A monitor on the other side operates not only on mutual exclusion but on condition variables as well. In a scenario where thread `T1` enters the monitor of an object thread `T2` intends to enter the same monitor, `T2` will wait until `T1` exits the monitor and in modern JVM `T2` will actually enter the monitor right after `T1` exits.